# Generating Arrival Counts Given Time

Tags: poisson-distribution, simulation, poisson-process

I'm looking to generate arrival counts given a length of time for a Poisson process. This is similar to [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136362/150323), however rather than generate the particular arrivals, I'd like to just get the final count.

As an example, given a Poisson distribution where we expect 1 arrival per second, I'd like to generate instances where over a period (let's say 10 seconds) we then yield arrival counts (such as 9, 13, 10, ...).

Currently, I'm simulating the inter-arrival times between arrivals, and when I reach my desired length of time, add up how many arrivals happened. However this seems inefficient if there is a way to just arrive at the final count.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

In R, the function `rpois` will take a random sample of specified size from a Poisson distribution of specified mean. If you expect $1$ arrival per second, then the mean arrival rate for 10 seconds is $\lambda = 10.$

You don't say for how many independent (i.e, disjoint) 10-second periods you want to generate arrivals. For $n = 15$ the simulation would be as follows:

```
set.seed(2019) # for reproducibility
lambda = 10;  n = 15
rpois(n, lambda)
 [1] 12  8  4 17  7 11 11  9 10 14
[11] 11 12  4  9 12
```

Numbers in brackets give the index of the first count on each line of output.

With a larger number of time periods, you could make a histogram of results and illustrate goodness of fit of the simulated sample to the population distribution $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 10).$
(With an even larger number of simulated counts, the fit of the histogram to the exact Poisson
distribution would tend to be better.)

[image]

Centers of open red circles are exact probabilities
of the distribution $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 10).$
R-code for making the figure is shown below.

```
set.seed(402);  lam = 10;  n = 5000
x = rpois(n, lam)
cutp = (-1:max(x))+.5
lbl = "Histogram of 1000 Counts from POIS(10)"
hist(x, prob=T, br=cutp, col="skyblue2", main=lbl)
  y = 0:30;  PDF = dpois(y, lam)
  points(y, PDF, col="red")
```

*Note:* Setting a seed for the pseudorandom number generator allows one to replicate a simulation experiment exactly. Omit the `set.seed` statement for a fresh simulation based on an unpredictable seed.