# How to generate a sequence of timestamps in R?

Tags: r, simulation, random-generation

For a clickstream simulation I require to generate sequences of randomly distributed timestamps.

Each sequence should:

- start and end between **sim_start** and **sim_end**,
- have **hit_count** number of timestamps

Comment: In a solution at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129322, I generated a process of random independent events with `cumsum(round(rexp(n.events, arrival.rate), 2))`. To achieve a specific number of such events, you could generate hit_count+1 of them, rescale into the intended time interval, and drop the first or last.

Comment: "random" is ambiguous. Do you want uniform or gaussian distribution, for example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Computers have different ways of storing time data. For example, R uses date-time classes `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`. From the documentation

> Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the
>   beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector.

So time is stored as a *number of seconds*

```
Sys.time()
## [1] "2017-02-03 10:34:35 CET"
as.numeric(Sys.time())
## [1] 1486114478
```

this means that if you want to sample timestamps, then you simply need to sample values from $0$ to $k$ (maximal number of seconds from the origin of choice), and then transform them to timestamps, e.g.

```
u <- runif(10, 0, 60) # "noise" to add or subtract from some timepoint
as.POSIXlt(u, origin = "2017-02-03 08:00:00") # sample 60 seconds starting from this origin (i.e. time 0)from this origin (i.e. time 0)
## [1] "2017-02-03 09:00:44 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:30 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:06 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:12 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:36 CET"
## [6] "2017-02-03 09:00:16 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:18 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:34 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:22 CET" "2017-02-03 09:00:35 CET"
```

Outside of R you also can follow such procedure by sampling some values and adding (or subtracting) them from some time-object like `=NOW()` in Excel or `systime` in databases etc.

Notice that this procedure enables you to sample from non-uniformly distributed time if you sample from different distribution, for example, normal distribution as in the example below.

```
hist(as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 08:00:00") + rnorm(1e6, 0, 60*60), 100)
```

[image: Randomly generated timestamps]

Comment: This procedure doesn't look quite right, because (a) the sample is discrete yet (b) does not allow for ties.  Real timestamps wouldn't behave like that: they would all be distinct, if represented with sufficient precision; and if coarsely rounded, there would be some ties.

Comment: @whuber notice that I use discrete sampling just as an example, in the second example I use continuous sampling. But I'll edit this for clarity.

Comment: I did notice that--but you use discrete sampling *without replacement*.

Comment: @whuber I didn't meant it, actually this was by mistake. Thanks for watching and for noticing me!